# How to change poms minversion and maxversion

Tags: maven, max, version, pom.xml, min

I need to change the minversion/maxversion in all of the projects poms; is there an mvn command for doing that?

Thank you in advance

pq

Comment: About which minversion/maxversion are you talking about? A pom.xml file in your post would be helpful ?

Comment: <goals>
                  <goal>vtweak</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <minversion>0</minversion>
                  <maxversion>1999</maxversion>
                  <deps>